# file permissions for php scripts which runs as apache user

Tags: php, apache

I don't think I fully understand groups and users. I have determined that php runs as user `apache`

I have 2 files on my server, but of which I can run without any problems. Below are the file permissions.

```
-rwxrwxr-x  1 staging staging     2100 Sep  6 14:47 hardware.php
-rwxrwxr-x  1 staging apache        69 Dec  5  2012 ipn.php
```

Is the only reason hardware.php can run is because it has read and execute permissions for `everyone`. What does php need to run?

Also I have a folder `migrations` with below permissions.

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 staging apache      4096 Dec 17 12:45 migrations
```

Is the reason I can write to this because the group is apache and the group has write permissions?

I am still a bit confused by users and groups. I know that groups can contain a collection of users, but I am not sure where to lookup the information.

Is apache a user or a group?

Answer (score 1):

> What does php need to run?

It needs one of these:

- Read access for everyone (`chmod o+r`)
- File belongs to the user `apache` (`chown apache`)
- File belongs to the group `apache` (`chgrp apache`)

> Is the reason I can write to this because the group is apache and the group has write permissions?

Yes.

> Is apache a user or a group?

There usually is a group *and* a user with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I set all of my Apache web files to 644 and my directories to 755. Check out this useful guide: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-linux-file-permissions-work/

644 means that files are readable and writeable by the owner of the file and readable by users in the group owner of that file and readable by everyone else.

755 is the same thing, it just has the execute bit set for everyone. The execute bit is needed to be able to change into the directory. This is why directories are commonly set to 755.

Apache is a user, in a group called apache.